# Conditionally assigning a controller's instance variable based on a shared has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, conditional-statements, parameters, instance-variables

I have a `Board` model that either belongs to an `Artist` or an `Album` in a `has_one` relationship:

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :board
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :board
end

class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :album
end
```

This is also reflected in my routes:

```
resources :artists do
  resource :board, only: :show
end

resources :albums do
  resource :board, only: :show
end
```

The problem arises when I need to assign an instance variable for either `artists/1/board` or `albums/1/board`. I thought of assigning the value on the basis of the `params[:artist_id]` or `params[:album_id]` but that doesn't seem to work:

```
class BoardsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    params[:artist_id] ? @board = Board.find(params[:artist_id]) : @board = Board.find(params[:album_id])
  end
end
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: That's not a valid `show` route. It should either be `artists/2/board/1` or `albums/2/board/1`. If you don't need to authenticate the `artist` or the `board`, then you can just use `@board = Board.find(params[:id])`

Comment: That's what I meant. Thanks for pointing out that typo.

Comment: Are you assigning `@album` or `@artist` for this action? Why are you defining a nested route since you only care about the board (as you have shown above)?

Comment: No. I want to be able to get to a board based on the artist or album it belongs to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def show
    @board = params[:artist_id].present? ? Artist.find(params[:artist_id]).board : Album.find(params[:album_id]).board
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Just from your own opinion, would you recommend loading instance variables this way or is there a better alternative? This was the just something I thought of doing off the top of my head.

Comment: And just out of curiosity, is `present?` required to get this to work?

Comment: For a simple case like this, this works fine. Also the `present?` is not required in this case.